# How to login into root user using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am using Robot Framework along with SSHLibrary.
I want to connect to a remote server using username and password. Afterwards login into root user with the password.

TestCase written till now:-

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SSHLibrary

*** Variables ***
${Hadoop_Test_Cluster}    xx.xxx.xxx.xx
${Hadoop_username}    yuvraj.gupta
${Hadoop_passwd}    ######

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    Open Connection    ${Hadoop_Test_Cluster}
    Login    ${Hadoop_username}    ${Hadoop_passwd}
    Write    sudo su 
    Write    ${Hadoop_passwd}
    ${whoami}    Execute Command    whoami
    Log    ${whoami}
```

As per my expectations whoami should print as root. Instead it is still printing my username (i.e. yuvraj.gupta) which means it hasn't been able to perform sudo su action properly.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to run whoami command using Write keyword and get effective user id to be **root**. Running whoami command using Execute Command keyword, the command executes in a new shell for which the effective user is not root but the user who logged in initially. Probably some one who has worked with sshlibrary code can throw a light on this behaviour since ExecuteCommand uses ConnectionCache from robot.utils package which stores information about current connection.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SSHLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
ssh to remote host and write sudo
    ${index}=    Open Connection    192.168.56.101    timeout=60s    prompt=$
    ${output}=    Run Keyword If    ${index} != 0    Login    abc    EveryD@y
    Should Contain    ${output}    abc@ubuntu:~$
    Write    sudo su -
    Write    EveryD@y
    Set Client Configuration    prompt=#
    ${output}=    Read Until Prompt
    Write    ls /root
    ${output}=    Read Until Prompt
    Write    whoami
    ${output}=    Read Until Prompt
    ${output}=    Execute Command    whoami
    Log    ${output}
    Close All Connections
```

-------OUTPUT--------

```
20160610 15:47:41.685 :  INFO : sudo su -
20160610 15:47:41.691 :  INFO : [sudo] password for abc:
20160610 15:47:41.747 :  INFO : root@ubuntu:~#
20160610 15:47:41.747 :  INFO : ${output} = root@ubuntu:~#
20160610 15:47:41.755 :  INFO : ls /root
20160610 15:47:41.758 :  INFO : 
${output} = xyz
root@ubuntu:~#
20160610 15:47:41.764 :  INFO : whoami
20160610 15:47:41.766 :  INFO : 
${output} = root
root@ubuntu:~#
20160610 15:47:41.768 :  INFO : Executing command 'whoami'.
20160610 15:47:41.781 :  INFO : ${output} = abc
20160610 15:47:41.782 :  INFO : abc
Ending test:   Sshlibrary3.ssh to remote host and write sudo
```

Comment: I am facing problems using your script.

20160613 10:53:56.284 :  INFO : sudo su -
20160613 10:53:56.481 :  INFO : [sudo] password for yuvraj.gupta:
20160613 10:53:56.483 :  FAIL : Prompt is not set

Comment: Please login to your target machine and check the prompts and then set them during Open Connection and Set Client Configuration